# switching SVN branch in local without checking out all the content

Tags: git, svn

*Is that possible to switch from one branch to another for work, without checking out the whole branch every time? (while saving any changes so I can switch back)*

**Scenario:**
I am working on an enterprise application, which has code base in SVN of extremely large size.
My problem is I always have to work on several branches at the same time, where most codes actually remain the same.
Checkout out those code as separate copy is a great overhead for me, in terms of time and diskspace.

**possible solution?**

I am not sure whether git can help. Can I do a local branch on git then sync with another branch in SVN, such that it track the diff between branches and only the diff is kept in local file system?

Will git-svn be helpful? Also if possible I would like this operations to be done in eclipse.

p.s. As the svn repo is at enterprise level, I cant have any impact on it.

Thanks in advance@

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.switch) (described in more details [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.switchwc))?

Comment: Because the original poster "always have to work on several branches at the same time".  Since Subversion doesn't provide shelving yet, working with multiple branches in parallel using `svn switch` would require manual patch management via `svn diff` + `svn patch`.  Certainly doable but somewhat ugly.